# `a:active` inherit regular `a` styles

Tags: css

I'm trying to override the `active` style of links in a blanket fashion, to revert them to their normal state in cases where they can't be interacted with (e.g. while the area they're in is scrolling).

So, in my code, I have this:

```
.scrolling a:active {
  background-color: inherit !important;
  color: inherit important!;
}
```

Unfortunately, this makes it inherit the colors of whatever its containing element is in, not the colors of the link when not active. Is there any way to get these to adopt the regular anchor tag styles, regardless of what they are? I'd prefer not to have to create an override for every type of link that can appear on the page.

Clarification: I can't just do something like:

```
a, .scrolling a:active {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

because different links across the site use different coloring systems, so I'd need a style rule like this for each link type. (Which I suppose I could do, but I'd love to find a blanket rule I could just use, if it's out there.)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `inherit` confers the value from the element's parent, where legal. If you want those values to be the same as the link in its resting state, can you do:

```
.scrolling a:active, .scrolling a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

**Updated**

I don't see a way to do what you want. There is no way to interrogate the style values of the anchor in its resting state and pass that to the active state. You will have to do that manually, as indicated above, but LESS or SASS would likely make your job easier.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I'm stuck with a preprocessor mixin. Rather inconvenient.